# PySide6 Widget Lose Children After Being Added

Tags: python, qwidget, pyside6

I am generating UI based on json file contents at run time.

There is a QTab widget. In each tab there is a QScrollArea (parent=QTab) which  has a QWidget set for its contents and a QGridLayout to add the controls to.
We then add a series of custom QCheckBoxes with a series each of the same as children.
So it's something like

```
 _________________
|_|  X parent1    |
|_|      X child1 |
  |      X child2 |
  |  X parent2    |
  |      X child1 |
```

And so on.

When these custom checkboxes are being created the parent child relationship is intact.
As in, during the generation of the widgets I can do

```
                for c in checkbox.children():
                    print(f"child: {c.text()}")
```

And it works as expected. checkbox.children() contains the expected array of child widgets.

I have a signal in the custom widget for state change:

```
    stateChanged = Signal(Qt.CheckState)
```

and when the state is being changed I'm calling it like

```
        self.stateChanged.emit(self)
```

And I'm connecting that signal on the parent widgets like

```
                checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.check_children)
```

Then check_children does:

```
                if isinstance(child, MultiStateCheckBox):
                    print(child.text(), "State:", child.checkState())
```

If you look at widget.children() at this time it's an empty array.

I'm pretty new to this but I would have expected that a widget would keep it's parent/child relationships all throughout execution...

Comment: Please format your code and don't post only fragments of it.